# One text files 10000 words one per line how to group them

Tags: php, python, bash

I dont really know where to start with this code.

I have a textfile there is 1 word per line in it its quite big 10 000 lines. What i want is to group them 4 words per line.

So lets say my file look like this.

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
user6
user7
user8
```

and so on 10 000 lines

What i want to do is make another textfile with the output like

```
user1 user2 user3 user4
user5 user6 user7 user8
```

and so on for all those lines (it is one word per line)

So far ive got tips to do it like this:

```
paste -d " "  - - - - < filename.txt
```

But this do not work i dont know if there is a limitation it works fine when i try it on a file with only 10 lines of words. But in my big file it does not work.

So what i am thinking to solve this is to use while loops or similar. 
I would prefer it to be in BASH. Or is there any another way to do what i want to do?

Comment: How can you not know where to start? Do you know how to read a line? How to write a line? How to manipulate strings? At the very least, pick a language.

Comment: I dont know the best way of doing it. And no i do not know how to read and write lines. That is why i ask, this is how i learn and understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: Well perhaps you should start there - breaking your program down into small steps and researching how to take each step.

Comment: @ZaraRebeckaElisabethZentio Try `awk '{ORS=(NR%4?FS:RS)}1' file`

Answer (score 3):

Through `paste`,

```
$ paste -d' '  - - - - < file
user1 user2 user3 user4
user5 user6 user7 user8
```

Comment: that will just list them one per line.

Comment: @ZaraRebeckaElisabethZentio This works here. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tested on ubuntu and it just list them one by one when i do paste -d' '  - - - - < users.txt 

Users.txt is where all the lines are.

Comment: there must be a space between `-` symbols. Just post your extact command in pastebin and then post back the corresponding link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TKf6rm1C

users.txt is a file i got with 9000 words in one per line. What happends when i do that command is that it list the words one by one per line. So it wont group it.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the `modulus(%) operator` to perform something on every `nth` element. In this case, we need a `1` based index as opposed to a `0` based index.

```
// fake array
$days = array('day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5', 'day6', 'day7', 'day8');


foreach($days as $idx => $day):
    $idx++; // required because our array is 0 based
    if(($idx % 4) == 1):
        echo '<br/>'. $day;
    else:
        echo $day;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can enumerate over the file, which will give you the line number and the value of the line. Append the values of the line to a list, and when you are at a multiple of four, write the line.

```
with open('users.txt', 'rb') as infile, with open('output.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    output = []
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        output.append(line)
        if (i + 1) % 4 == 0:
            outline = " ".join(output)
            outfile.write(outline)
            outfile.write(os.linesep)
            output = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that Avinash Raj's paste command doesn't work for you.

Try this awk command:

`awk '{printf "%s%c", $0, (NR % 4)?" ":"\n"}; END{print ""}' infile >outfile`

where `infile` is the name of your input file & `outfile` is the name of your output file.

If you want the data to be printed in neat columns you can do something like

`awk '{printf "%8s%c", $0, (NR % 4)?" ":"\n"}; END{print ""}' infile >outfile`

That will make columns 8 chars wide, plus 1 space between each column. If any word is longer than 8 chars it won't get chopped off, it'll just throw the column alignment out on that line.

And if you want the columns to be flush left, change the format string to "%-8s%c", etc.